# How can I fix JavaScript error seen in Chrome, but not seen in Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, macos, safari-5

I'm using Chrome on Mac OS X Lion and recently the behavior of Craig's List changed.  If you go to a real estate or rental listing like [this one](http://chicago.craigslist.org/chc/apa/3797569024.html), only the first picture shows and there is no longer any animation shifting left on the other thumbnails as you hover your mouse over them and clicking the other thumbnails does not update the large picture shown to the right of the thumbnails.  If I use Safari, it works properly.

What could have changed on my computer to cause this and how might I restore the old correct behavior? Could I have somehow disabled JavaScript, if so, where would that be?

In the preferences of Chrome, I see that `Allow all sites to run JavaScript (recommended)` radio button is enabled, so I guess perhaps this is not a JavaScript being disabled issue? Is there a way to test JavaScript is functioning properly, perhaps by going to some special website?

In the JavaScript console window, I see this in red and hovering over the thumbnails causes the count of the `Property '$' of object ...` to increase:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
                                                         inject.aspx:75
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
                                                         postings.js:7
```